# Context.Request getValues and multiple select elements

Tags: c#, ashx, generic-handler

I am trying to understand the GetValues for Form and QueryString in context.Request

I have a url like this, generated from an ajax handler on a multiple select html element

```
generic.ashx?tags=1&tags=2
```

in theory shouldnt this (submitted by post) set the string tags to 1, 2?

```
string[] tags = context.Request.Form.GetValues("tags");
```

I have tried using the get method as well, using querystring or just context request, nothing so far

```
string[] tags = context.Request.QueryString.GetValues("tags");
string[] tags = context.Request.GetValues("tags");
```

My bottom line is i want to build a sql where clause

```
int tagscount = tags.Count();

      string sWhere ="";

        if (tagscount != 0) {
          sWhere ="Where (";
          for (int i = 0; i < tagscount; i++)

            {

                sWhere += " tag_id ="+tags[i]+")";
                if (i < tagscount -1){
                  sWhere += " OR ";
                }

              }
              sWhere += ")";
            }
```

but honestly i would just be thrilled at this point to show that my string is being populated

```
results = string.Format("{{ \"tags\": {0}  }}",tags);
context.Response.Write(results);
```

Comment: Are you sure that this doesn't populate the array with the two values you're expecting? var tags = context.Request.QueryString.GetValues("tags");

Answer (score 1):

GetValues() should work, instead of strictly getting values into string[], try using var and iterate to get each value from it.

```
var values = context.Request.QueryString.GetValues("tags");
foreach (var item in values)
{
    //do your thing
}
```